# Laravel Dompdf set starting page number

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

How can i set the starting page number? this is my code in dompdf:

```
<script type="text/php">

    if (isset($pdf)) {
        $pdf->page_script('
             if ($PAGE_COUNT > 1) {

                $font = $fontMetrics->getFont("TimesNewRoman", "regular");                    
                $pdf->page_text(515, 50, "{PAGE_NUM}", $font, 11, array(.5,.5,.5));

            }
        ');
   }
</script>
```

if i want to set the value of {PAGE_NUM} to start in the number 10.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved it using this code

```
<script type="text/php">
  if ( isset($pdf) ) {
    $pdf->numPage='{{$numPag}}';
      $pdf->page_script('
          if ($PAGE_NUM > 1 ) {

              $pdf->numPage++;

              $font = $fontMetrics->getFont("TimesNewRoman", "regular");                    
              $pdf->text(510, 50, $pdf->numPage, $font, 11, array(.5,.5,.5));

          }
     ');
  }
   </script>
```